# Can vim be configured to use an alternate ftp client

Tags: vim, ftp, windows-7-x64, passive-mode

This post is related to a SuperUser [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1034347/how-to-set-up-vim-for-passive-ftp) I entered recently. I am re-asking the question here, because I feel either rebuilding vim or advanced configuration may be involved.

I'm trying to configure vim to use passive ftp when I enter an edit command like

`: e ftp://ics@steamboy//home/ics/.bashrc`

Right now I get an error indicating our Kaspersky anti-virus is preventing active ftp.

I believe that vim 7.4 has ftp already built into it. I have searched vim help to see if there are variables that can be set to use a a different command line ftp client, like [passive_ftp](http://passive-ftp.com/). I could not find anything except to set an scp client.

Any suggestions to fix this or information links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim does not have ftp client built in, AFAIK; it's all `netrw` calling various *NIX utilities. As for variables... in the same table where there's the variable for `scp` client, there's also variables for all other protocols' clients:

```
:help g:netrw_ftp_cmd
```

So basically you could do this in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:netrw_ftp_cmd="your_command --your_switches"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a whirl.